# Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable (C++)

Tags: c++, nodes

On the line "placeholder->next = NULL;" I get an error of a potential uninitialized local variable. Any advice is appreciated.

```
Node * ptr;
Node * placeholder;
if (head == NULL)
{
    cout << "Please add something to the list before deleting." << endl;
    return menu();
}
else
{
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        ptr = head;
        head = NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            placeholder = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        placeholder->next = NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about that error message? Just initialize your pointer variables (e.g. with `nullptr`). Here's the line where your pointer variable might be used uninitialized `placeholder->next = NULL;`.

Comment: There is no reason why ptr->next != NULL should be true, so compiler warns that placeholder might not be initialized. Therefore Node * placeholder=NULL; should delete the warning and add a test if(placeholder!=NULL) before doing placeholder->next = NULL;

Comment: @NPE: In fact, we cannot have `ptr->next == nullptr`  when `head->next != nullptr` as `ptr = head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler fail to see the fact that

```
while (ptr->next != nullptr)
{
    placeholder = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

runs at least once due to previous workflow.

Safer is to always initialize variable:

```
Node* ptr = nullptr;
Node* placeholder = nullptr;
```

(even if deferencing `nullptr` is UB, as deferencing uninitalized pointer.)

Even better is to reduce scope of the variable, which allow to give better initalization:

```
if (head == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Please add something to the list before deleting." << std::endl;
    return menu();
}
if (head->next == nullptr)
{
    Node* ptr = head;
    head = nullptr;
    free(ptr);
}
else
{
    Node* placeholder = head;
    Node* ptr = head->next;

    while (ptr->next != nullptr)
    {
        placeholder = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    placeholder->next = nullptr;
    free(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring  pointer named as placeholder, simply write

`placeholder=nullptr`

Comment: `nullptr` would be better